# Nibs cause app to crash in iOS 9 Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am attempting to use a Nib file in my app, which is being built in Xcode 7 beta. Whenever I try to run the app, I get an error saying "Failed to update auto layout status: The agent crashed". The IBDesignable nib doesn't update in the storyboard, and when I try to run the app, it crashes. Is anybody else having this issue on the Xcode 7 beta? Are there any fixes?

Comment: Do you have any other messages, say about illegal NSLayoutConstraints? We get a crash then and are working to fix our constraints.

Comment: @PaulCezanne nothing about constraints. It sends me three errors, all saying "Failed to update auto layout status: The agent crashed". Those are the only three errors.